# app crashing when responding to tapgesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I have a UIViewController with a xib built for holding content in a UIScrollView. this gets populated from an RSS feed. this works as expected. I want a tap on the UIView that the view controller owns to respond to a tap and continue on its way. however, a tap crashes the app with the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. I really have no clue what's going on.

The .h file of the xib's view controller looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *article_image;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *article_title;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *article_date;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *preview_image;

- (void) loadPreviewImage;
```

Then the .m file looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGesture)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5;
    self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

}

- (void) singleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"TAPPED!");
}
```

Even if I put just a simple roundrectbutton in the xib and attach it to an IBAction - it crashes, so I'm figuring there's something wrong with how my xib is set up, but I have no clue as to what. those properties in the .h get populated just fine from the VC that holds the scrollview, so the xib obviously knows the file it's associated with, so I just can't figure out why it's crashing and throwing that error on a tap.

Comment: whats does the crash report day ?

Comment: Also your IBOutlets should be (nonatomic, weak)

Answer (score 1):

The fix is this:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGesture:)];
```

notice the `:` at the end of the selector.

Indeed, your action method signature is:

```
- (void) singleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
```

while

```
@selector(singleTapGesture)
```

would rather identify:

```
- (void) singleTapGesture;
```

Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: thanks for the response, sergio. that's actually what i started with so that posted code was me trying to go back and clean up all i've tried ... and clearly left that out. regardless, just to try, i put it back in and ... same issue, though the console reports nothing but (lldb) on a tap and crash.

Comment: put a breakpoint on exceptions to see where exactly the crash happens... or can you already see the stack trace after the crash on the left side of your Xcode window? what's in there?

Comment: yes, it's throwing a trace ... dunno if this screenshot does much to help, but here it is: http://i.imgur.com/KgnWVfY.png

Comment: the reference to self.view adds the drop shadow properly, so that can't be the problem. all the props in the .h (labels and one image view) get populated properly as well. so the xib knows the file owner. this is why i'm like wtf? why is is throwing THAT error when the selector is most definitely there.

Comment: you haven't set the exception catcher breakpoint: go to the breakpoint pane (the sixth from the left, just right of the stack trace you posted), and click the "+" button choosing "exception breakpoint", then "done" and rerun...

Comment: with that, there's a new error it's throwing: -[__NSArrayM singleTapGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: here's where all the objects are created: http://i.imgur.com/TIsJt9b.png - BBItemObject is just a value object to hold the data, BBItem is just the view for showing it in the scrollview. that's also the object being troublesome here.

Comment: it looks like your `view` gets deallocated at some point but the gesture recognizer is still hanging there. Would you mind doing: ` UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGesture:)] autorelease];` -- this would also get rid of memory leak. You will possibly still get a crash but I hope an earlier one.

Comment: Do it without the auto release.

Comment: @t.h.: if you are using ARC, what are those `retain` doing in your .h file?

Answer (score 0):

well, i never really figured out exactly what was causing the crash - so i wound adding the gesture recognizer to the objects into the loop that builds them and all works great. not how i'd like to have done it (was trying to keep it in the object's class definition) but whatever. perhaps this will help someone else.